# Error 503 al cargar un modulo de mi pagina

Tags: c#

Cordial saludo.
Actualmente he tenido problemas con un modulo de mi pagina. Cuando doy clic sobre el, aparece inmediatamente el error 503 servicio no disponible pero cuando regreso a la pagina y doy clic en un modulo diferente, puedo ver que función bien, así que el problema solo lo tengo con un modulo.
He revisado los métodos que recibo de un web API en mi código del archivo con extensión .ascx.cs y funcionan correctamente, pero aun no logro identificar el error en el código, ya que asumo que es u bug.
He realizado debug a cada fragmento de código en el archivo con extensión .ascx.cs, pero al parecer, todo esta okey.

En primer lugar comparto el código del archivo .ascx con el cual genero la pagina

Codigo .ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AFArchivadoresRegistro.ascx.cs" Inherits="DesktopModules_AF_AFArchivadoresRegistro" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/DesktopModules/AF/Comunes/MensajesControl.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="MensajesControl" %>
<uc1:MensajesControl runat="server" ID="MensajesControl" />

<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Equipo</th>
                <th>Tipo de Equipo</th>
                <th>Contenido</th>
                <th>Detalle</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                 <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DDLEqu" DataTextField="obras" DataValueField="obras" 
                        AutoPostBack="true">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="Requerido" ControlToValidate="DDLEqu" 
                        runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Edicion" ForeColor="Red" />
                     <asp:CustomValidator ErrorMessage="Ya insertada" ControlToValidate="DDLEqu" 
                        runat="server" ID="CVRegBasDat" OnServerValidate="CVRegBasDat_ServerValidate" 
                        Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Edicion" ForeColor="Red" />
                     <asp:CustomValidator ErrorMessage="Ya registrada" ControlToValidate="TBDia"
                        runat="server" ID="CVRegViewState" OnServerValidate="CVRegViewState_ServerValidate" 
                        Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Edicion" ForeColor="Red" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DDLTipEqu" DataTextField="Lista" DataValueField="Lista" 
                        AutoPostBack="true">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="Requerido" ControlToValidate="DDLTipEqu" 
                        runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Edicion" ForeColor="Red" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DDLCon" DataTextField="Lista" DataValueField="Lista" 
                        AutoPostBack="true">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="Requerido" ControlToValidate="DDLCon" 
                        runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Edicion" ForeColor="Red" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DDLDet" DataTextField="Lista" DataValueField="Lista" 
                        AutoPostBack="true">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="Requerido" ControlToValidate="DDLDet" 
                        runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Edicion" ForeColor="Red" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton Text="Registrar" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-sm btn-success" 
                        ID="LBReg" OnClick="LBReg_Click" ValidationGroup="Edicion" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GVTab" CssClass="table" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Equipo" DataField="Equipo" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Tipo de Equipo" DataField="TipoEquipo" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Contenido" DataField="Contenido" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Detalle" DataField="Detalle" />
            </Columns>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <div class="alert alert-info">
                    No ha ingresado documentos aún.
                </div>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
        </asp:GridView>
        <td>
            <asp:LinkButton Text="Insertar" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-sm btn-success" ID="LBIns" 
                OnClick="LBIns_Click" />
        </td>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Agradecemos la ayuda.

Comment: ¿Hay algún Log del server que sea de utilidad?

Comment: Cordial saludo.
fredyfx, como puedo acceder a los logs?
La falla la estoy teniendo en local.
Gracias.

Comment: En Windows Server -> Event Viewer -> Windows Logs -> Applications y por algún lado ha de haber el registro de dicho error. En Local, debería haber algo en la consola o en la clásica pantalla amarilla. Saludos. PD: Recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada haciendo click en el check del costado de la respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordial saludo.
La falla la tenia en esta línea:

```
 <asp:CustomValidator ErrorMessage="Ya registrada" ControlToValidate="TBDia"
```

El nombre del ControlToValidate era realmente DDLEqu.

Corregí el nombre y la pagina ahora funciona correctamente.